# Algorithm2e package for loop increment

Tags: formatting, algorithm2e

I could not find in the manual how to increment a for loop in the `algorithm2e` package.

I want to something like this:

```
for(i=0; i<10, i=i+2){
 do something;
}
```

Answer (score 32):

Somehow `algorithm2e` has `\KwTo` but not `\KwBy`.  It is easy to define it, however:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\pagestyle{empty}
\SetKw{KwBy}{by}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
  \For{$i\gets0$ \KwTo $8$ \KwBy $2$}{
    Do something
    }
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 13):

You can redefine the way `\For` works:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[noline]{algorithm2e}

\SetKwFor{For}{for (}{) $\lbrace$}{$\rbrace$}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \For{$i = 0;\ i < 10;\ i = i + 2$}{
    Do something\;
  }
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How do I add multiple lines in the for loop? Using `\;` after each statement doesn't work, they just get concatenated into a long line

Comment: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vVX2.png) is what I get with [this code](https://pastebin.com/raw/KPx2NPeh). I can add multiple lines without problem. Perhaps show a [complete, minimal example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764) that replicates your issue.

Comment: I managed to fix it by adding a whitespace between the end of line and `\;`