# How to write this algorithm in latex?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e

I use the following code for my project I can't write it

```
for j = l :n 
    if j > 1 
        A(j:n,j) = A(j:n, j) - A(j:n, l :j - l )·A(j, l:j - l )T 
    end 
    A(j:n, j) = A(j:n, j) / J A(j,j) 
end
```

I use the package for this

```
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
```

I tried to write but I didn't find any solution please help :
I sovle it :) [image]

Comment: You need to check the documentation of [algorithm2e](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/doc/algorithm2e.pdf) which is very helpful. Also, your code doesn't stand as a minimal working example.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[noline]{algorithm2e}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/362194/2288
\SetKwFor{For}{for }{}{end}

\begin{document}
    \begin{algorithm}
        \For{j = l :n}{
            \If{j > 1}{
                A(j:n,j) = A(j:n, j) - A(j:n, l :j - l )·A(j, l:j - l )T 
            }
            A(j:n, j) = A(j:n, j) / J A(j,j)  
        }
    \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```